# My entity in EF doesn't connet with other entites that has relation with them

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I design my model using EF6 .I have 2 entities **User** and **Company** ,and user can register 1 or more than 1 companies in system my entities are like this :

```
 public partial class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            this.Ideas = new HashSet<Idea>();
            this.Companies = new HashSet<Company>();
        }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("نام")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "را وارد کنید")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("نام خانوادگی")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "را وارد کنید")]
    public string Family { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("تحصیلات")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "را انتخاب کنید")]
    public string EducationLevel { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("دانشگاه")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "را وارد کنید")]
    public string University { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("کد ملی")]
    [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "باید ده رقمی باشد", MinimumLength = 10)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "را وارد نمایید")]
    public string IntCode { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("سطح دسترسی")]
    public string Permission { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("کلمه عبور")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "را وارد نمایید")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("تاریخ ثبت نام")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMapped]


    public virtual ICollection<Idea> Ideas { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

And my company entity :

```
 public partial class Company
    {
        public Company()
        {
            this.CompanyMembers = new HashSet<CompanyMember>();
            this.Activities = new HashSet<Activity>();
            this.Attachments = new HashSet<Attachment>();
            this.Publications = new HashSet<Publication>();
        }

        [DisplayName("شناسه")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DisplayName(" نام شرکت")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "را وارد نمایید")]
        public string Name { get; set; }



        [DisplayName("آدرس وب سایت شرکت")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "را وارد نمایید")]
        public string Website { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<CompanyMember> CompanyMembers { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Publication> Publications { get; set; }
    }
```

These two entities has relation on **UserId** column .I write a abstract for my repository,as you can see here :

```
 public abstract class GenericRepository<C, T> :
    IGenericRepository<T>
        where T : class
        where C : DbContext, new()
    {

        private C _entities = new C();
        public C Context
        {

            get { return _entities; }
            set { _entities = value; }
        }

        public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
        {

            IQueryable<T> query = _entities.Set<T>();
            return query;
        }

        public IQueryable<T> FindBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {

            IQueryable<T> query = _entities.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
            return query;
        }}
```

So i create a **userrepository** :

```
namespace Repository
{
  public  class userRepository:GenericRepository<InModelContainer,User>
  {
}}
```

Now my problem is ,i want to write a query like this :

```
    public ActionResult Index(int companyId)
        {
            int id = objUserRepository.FindBy(i => i.Email == User.Identity.Name).First().Id;

     if( objUserRepository.FindBy(i=>i.Id==id & i.Companies.id==compnayid).Count()==1){do something}
}
```

It doesn't work ie this part(in if condition) **id==compnayid** doesn't resolve ?!!!why ?

Comment: Are you purposefully using the binary & as opposed to &&?

Comment: No i just want to check both condition in my find clause!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User has collection of companies and you cannot access property of companies by using dot, so you have to change query form

`objUserRepository.FindBy(i=>i.Id==id & i.Companies.id==compnayid).Count()==1)`

to

```
objUserRepository.FindBy(i=>i.Id==id && i.Companies.Any(c => c.id==compnayid)).Count()==1)
```

Comment: Thanks ,can you give me some help about **Any** ?

Comment: Any بر اساس شرطی که در داخل آن نوشته میشود یک مقدار بولین برمیگردونه. در این کد اگە شرکتی با ای دی مورد نظر پیدا بشه مقدار ترو برمیگردونه.

Comment: If there is more that one records in company  does it return true?

Comment: mamnon @mo.esmp:::DDD